# Confuse about the result of my check null value code

Tags: scala, h2o

I tried this to check whether a row is null or not.

```js
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._

class Miss extends MRTask {
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
      if(c.atd(row) == 0){  
       nc.addNum(0)
      }
      else
       nc.addNum(1)
    }
  }
}
```

And I can not understand the result of my code here

```js
           A    B    C    D            E   check
    min                                     0
   mean                                     0
 stddev                                     0
    max                                     1
missing                                     0
      0  5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      1  4.9    3  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      2  4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      3  4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      4    5  3.6  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      5  5.4  3.9  1.7  0.4  Iris-setosa    1
      6  4.6  3.4  1.4  0.3  Iris-setosa    1
      7    5  3.4  1.5  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      8  4.4  2.9  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      9  4.9  3.1  1.5  0.1  Iris-setos...
```

In the code generate check column, Why my max row is 1? I'm new to h2oFrame, can anyone help me understand this? IS there something wrong with my code? Thx

Answer (score 1):

you are appending a new column which includes only 0,1 values.
Hence minimum value stored in the column is 0. Maximum value stored in the column is 1. In this case, mean==0 is suspicious, that's probably a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved this one! Can you help me take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442536/how-to-parametrize-class-and-implement-method-depends-on-type-in-scala