# Can I use IsNull or na in if() to check missing value?

Tags: scala, h2o

This one is not duplicate I have new question. I tried to write this

```
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._

class Miss extends MRTask {
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
      if(c.atd(row) == 0){  
       nc.addNum(0)
      }
      else
       nc.addNum(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Can I use na or IsNull in `if (...)` to check whether or not that `row` is null?

Code result

```
          A    B    C    D            E    NaN
    min                                     0
   mean                                     0
 stddev                                     0
    max                                     1
missing                                     0
      0  5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      1  4.9    3  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      2  4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      3  4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      4    5  3.6  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      5  5.4  3.9  1.7  0.4  Iris-setosa    1
      6  4.6  3.4  1.4  0.3  Iris-setosa    1
      7    5  3.4  1.5  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      8  4.4  2.9  1.4  0.2  Iris-setosa    1
      9  4.9  3.1  1.5  0.1  Iris-setos...
```

Comment: `row` cannot be null, it is an integer

Comment: So if in the original csv file that row is empty, after I convert csv to H2Oframe what kind of intger will that row have?

Comment: Do you think my code is correct for checking missing value in H2oframe? The result of my code is weird..

Comment: @kukido I post my code and result here. Really appreciate your help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399663/confuse-about-the-result-of-my-check-null-value-code

Comment: Use if x.isNaN for c.atd(row) check.

Comment: you mean if (c.atd(row).isNaN)? Can you post an answer code line...Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Asking the same question over and over again doesn't give you more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
c.atd(row) match {
  case nan: Double if nan.isNaN => nc.addNum(0)
  case 0 => nc.addNum(0)
  case _ => nc.addNum(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what does case_ mean? I post My result the max row is still 1

Comment: case _ means default, if the value was not matched to any of the previous cases, so it is neither 0 nor NaN.

Comment: why not add a print statement? default => println(default); nc.addNum(1);

Comment: Can you tell me whats wrong with my original code? Thanks